# Is there any way to set type of ViewBag item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

Like in topic. It is possible to do it? Or make something to use ViewBag items in place where we need no dynamic item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a dynamic item, just declare a variable with the ViewBag's "static" type :

```
@IList<MyType> mylist= ViewBag.ListOfItemsOfMyType;
```

and use mylist

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to create `View model` and use that `model` in your `View` rather then `ViewBag`.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not preferable, since you probably should use a model in that case, but in the view, you can always cast the viewbag property into a type, if you need it to be an int for instance,

```
int number = (int)ViewBag.MyNumber;
```